# Style multiple pickerViews in one view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uilabel, uipickerview

I am an experienced programmer, but new to developing iOS apps.

I have a view controller containing two pickerView controllers, each parsing a different array. Works like a charme, however I am now trying to style them as follows:

```
// Code to style pickerView, but viewForRow returns invalid row when using
// multiple instances of pickerView controller in one view controller
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
    if (pickerLabel == nil) {
        //label size
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80, 32);
        pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
        [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
        //here you can play with fonts
        [pickerLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:15.0]];
    }

    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        [pickerLabel setText: [self.arrayLeagues objectAtIndex:row]];
    } else {
        [pickerLabel setText: [self.arrayEvents objectAtIndex:row]];
    }

    return pickerLabel;
}
```

This makes the app crash and resulting in the following error:

```
-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

The crash seems to be caused because of the 'row' variable (... viewForRow: (NSInteger)row ...) not reseting when using multiple pickerViews in one viewController.

Any tips on resolving this?

***Edit***

I found out that the problem was caused by a typo in my code. The code below actually works the way it should. So if you need to update Font or other properties of the UIPickerView, go ahead and use this :)

Comment: CHeck your array your are getting value of array at index number 3 but array has only 2 [0,1,2] index.

Comment: That in fact is caused by the second pickerView. So the first array has 3 values (0-2). The erroneous index 3 is the next row from the second pickerView. 'viewForRow: (NSInteger)row' does not seem to reset when using multiple instances of the pickerView controller in one view.